# How to resize website "banner" to fit different size windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried a few different things to fix this, but I have

```
#serverselect{
      color: white;
      background: black;
      /*TOP BAR COLOR DOJCAD is #2196f3*/
      font-family: Roboto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```
      <select id="server" style= "background-color: #000000 ; color: #FFFFFF" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Select A Server</option>
            <option value="?server=1">1</option>
            <option value="?server=2">2</option>
            <option value="?server=3">3</option>
            <option value="?server=4">4</option>
            <option value="?server=5">5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

When I make the window smaller, the "banner" clutters up and makes it unusable. See linked images.

Incorrect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln4Fz.jpg
Correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnr6U.jpg

Comment: Add property `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: It still looks the same with that added